# Cannot load the script with the type "module"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

In the file `script.js` there are features of `ES6` like `import`. For this, I connect `script.js` as a `module`,  without the `type = 'module'` the browser generates an error. But when I connect the script

```
<script type = "module" src = "script.js"> </ script>
```

as a `module`, in the `Chrome browser (v67)`, the console pops up an error:

> Access to Script at 'file: /// D: /PROJECT/playing_field/src/script.js' 
>      from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. 
>      Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

how to connect a script as a module?

Comment: Use a web server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to serve your page with a Web server. If you didn't have already one configured and are using Google Chrome, you can use the [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb).